# jsfiddle post error fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, jsfiddle

I'm trying to set up a JSFiddle for a FullCalendar project that I'm working on, but am getting stuck near the beginning.

[Here's the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/L77scdfs/8/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
  defaultView:'agendaWeek',
    defaultDate: '2018-01-18',
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    snapDuration: '02:00:00'
});
```

When I "view frame source" in Chrome I get an error of "{"error": "Please use POST request"}".  (Viewing in Firefox yields the expected the html code, but the calendar still doesn't work as expected; i.e., no time slots.)  From previous reading, this seems to come up when using forms with method of "get" or improper AJAX, but I'm not using forms or AJAX here.

I've tried adjusting the order of the external .js and .css resources to no avail.  Is there an option I need to set in FullCalendar I need to get this to work?  Or more external resources to include?

Thank you in advance for reading this and providing any guidance that you can.

Comment: Which version of Chrome? I don't get that error when clicking it (Chrome 63). And what does viewing the frame source (which is just a browser tool operation) have to do with the functionality or the order of the JS and CSS?

Comment: I guess it doesn't.  Sorry, I don't do a lot of js development, and was just fumbling around in the dark to figure out what was wrong.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was including unnecessary (and probably conflicting?) external resources.  By removing bootstrap and fullcalendar's print.css, I got it to work as expected.